# 2GFSK 9600bps Transmitter and amplifier for 433 MHz

Tags: uhf, transceiver, transmitter, amplifier

I'm looking for a reliable, however cheap solution for ground-space communication. I need at least 50W of transmitted power with 2GFSK modulation at 70cm band (433 MHz). Transmission will be done between earth's surface and a cubesat on LEO at 9600bps.

- What should I be looking for?
- Is SDR + amplifier a good solution?
- Or should I aim at transceivers  with capability of transmitting 50W with 2GFSK modulation (if any like that exist), or
- maybe should I aim for creating my own solution?

Comment: Sorry, but we don't allow questions which are purely requests for product recommendations.

Comment: @KevinReidAG6YO Reworded the question, I hope this works now. I'm really desperate about this information.

Comment: @KevinReidAG6YO Thank you!

Comment: I'm not familiar wtih 2GFSK, but other forms of FSK can be accomplished with an SSB (or all-mode) transceiver which would be capable of 50W, That's assuming that transmitting on that frequency at that power is legal in your area.

Comment: You neglected to state the required symbol rate and deviation for your application. How will you interface the data to the transmitter?

Comment: As a communications engineer, when someone approaches me with "I have already decided on a band, and on a modulation, and on a minimum power, now I need a transmitter", I go "hmmm. I don't know what solves your problem, but I can virtually guarantee that you've started to specify at  the wrong end of your system". Instead of asking us where/how to get a 50W GFSK  transmitter, maybe start with "Hi, I want to {application} over {distance}, within the constraints that it needs to {requirements}. Far as I can see, the minimum net data rate needs to be {rate}.". Could you add that to your question?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm aware, however I need transmitter for a specific device. The question concerns a Cubesat which will end up on LEO. The receiver on the cubesat supoorts 2GFSK 9600bps at 433MHz

Comment: @leller that's **more than critical info** and should be part of your question, not just some comment! Please edit your question to state what you've just said.

Comment: @MarcusMüller edited the question

Comment: Thanks! So, 9600 bd GFSK isn't a full PHY description, leave alone a full description of the modem you need. But since this is satellite equipment, chances are very high that this follows some specific standard (most likely some CCSDS standard); can you find out which standard that satellite-side modem follows? Most likely, the type of modem would be a good start, too. ( I feel like you have a lot of info that you could *easily* share that would make answering a lot easier)

Comment: @MarcusMüller the receiving, on-satellite module is equipped with si446x chip (half-duplex, 443MHz, 2GFSK 9600bps)

Comment: OK, so what are you going to use for FEC, framing? Does this mean the ground station is solely responsible for Doppler correction?

Comment: also, seriously, what about you just add as much info as possible to your question? It's a bit unproductive to spend hours just question-answer ping-ponging. In essence, you should give as much info as possible in your question instead of making us guess.